# OpenERP server prob message when installing an app [Errno 13] python permission

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, permissions, odoo

I recently installed open erp v7 on ubuntu 13.10, I could install the warehouse app fine, as well as the sales app , but I'm having trouble installing a few other apps. It looks like it is either a permission problem ( although I doubt it as the warehouse and sales apps installed without any problem ) or a python related problem. I have no clue on what I must do. Any help would be great. Here is the message I got below:

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 682, in install_from_urls
    shutil.move(os.path.join(tmp, module_name), module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 298, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 177, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/product_custom_attributes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the (linux-)user running the openerp server doesn't have the right to create a directory on a specific destination (maybe /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/product_custom_attributes).
so try to set the access rights on your linux-server correct.